# Combine and reconcile forecasts

Tags: regression, forecasting, panel-data, quantile-regression, forecast-combination

I am struggling conceptually with how I can best model my panel dataset. I have a set of individual data and I need to:

1) estimate the median value of the dependent variable over time in the entire population;

2) compute individual-level forecasts of the dependent variable

A quantile regression on macroeconomic data provide very good forecasts for 1), but is insufficient to explain individual variability. Conversely, a micro-based regression seems well-suited for 2), but results in a poor aggregate median forecast.

Do you have any suggestion about how to combine and reconcile these forecasts?